# using AWK to edit a csv file

Tags: awk

I have a csv file in which I have 2 columns (1st column is a number and 2nd is a sequence of characters) like this small example:

```
45373,VAREAKAVVLRDRKSTRLN
1678,SCTFAEGMLFEDCCGP
1524,SCPHFWLAECGP
20,SCTFAEGMLFEDCCGP
```

I want to look for the similar sequences of characters in the 2nd field and if they are similar I would sum up the corresponding 1st column for the similar rows. for instance for the above example the 2nd and the 4th rows have similar sequences of characters (2nd field) and in the below expected output I summed up the 1st field of those rows and put them in the single row:

expected output:

```
45373,VAREAKAVVLRDRKSTRLN
1698,SCTFAEGMLFEDCCGP
1524,SCPHFWLAECGP
```

to get the expected output I made the following command in AWK:

```
awk -F "," ({for(i=2;i<NF;i++){t+=$i==$(i+1)}}t==NF)) { print } }' infile.csv > outfile.csv
```

but it does not return the expected output. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Please say "identical" instead of "similar" if that's what you mean. Of course identical strings are trivially similar, too, but the word suggests that minor differences would be tolerated, and begs the question how much they are allowed to differ.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the output order:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{str[$2]+=$1} END {for(s in str) print str[s], s}' infile.csv
```

Comment: If you change `-vOFS=,` to `-v OFS=,` than that'll work in any awk, not just in GNU awk.

Answer (score 0):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task as follows, let `file.txt` content be

```
45373,VAREAKAVVLRDRKSTRLN
1678,SCTFAEGMLFEDCCGP
1524,SCPHFWLAECGP
20,SCTFAEGMLFEDCCGP
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{arr[$2]+=$1}END{for(i in arr){print arr[i],i}}' file.txt
```

output

```
1524,SCPHFWLAECGP
1698,SCTFAEGMLFEDCCGP
45373,VAREAKAVVLRDRKSTRLN
```

Explanation: I set both field separator (`FS`) and output field separator (`OFS`) to `,`. I use array `arr` to store total for given `$2`, which I computed by adding value of `$1` for each line. In `END` I do print all `$2` - total pairs using `for`. **Disclaimer:** my solution assume you are happy with any order of rows in output

(gawk 4.2.1)